# Node-config custom-environment-variables not Picking Docker environment Variables

Tags: node-config

**Working on Windows OS.**

My node app using node-config isn't using docker environment variables. It's  always using the default config.

I am using node-config custom environment variables as described here: https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Environment-Variables#custom-environment-variables

Everything is working well when running the app locally. The config by passes the default ones and takes the ones defined in my User variables when set.

**Problem**

- I start a docker instance with all required Environment variables
  set.
- I verify the env variables by running `docker exec container_name env`

However, the node app still uses the default config, instead of the environment variables.

I am not sure what setup I may be missing.

Comment: sorry this isn't an answer to your problem, but I have this exact issue with Heroku. the custom-environment-variables don't override the default or production json files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a maintainer of `node-config`. I don't test with Docker or Heroku, but this most be an ordering problem. As long as the environment variables are set before `require('config')` happens, they will work-- at that point Docker or Heroku doesn't matter. The activity is happening inside the Node.js JavaScript engine at that point.

Try this simple test: Just before your line where you `require('config')`, use `console.log` or an equivalent to print out the environment variables that you care about. I expect you'll find that when it's not working it's because the environment variables are not set before `node-config` is loaded.